# How to read data from other form?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to read data from Form2 in main form?

```
private void GSMStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 settings = new Form2();
        settings.ShowDialog();

       //TextBox.Text=TextfromForm2
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Forms application, how to communicate between custom controls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389057/windows-forms-application-how-to-communicate-between-custom-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create public property on Form2 class and assign value to that property. Then you can read that property like `TextBox.Text=settings.Property` on Main Form.

Answer (score 0):

On the form you want to expose the data from, add a public property to return the private data elements.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add public Properties to Form2. Then, after setting them in Form2, you can reference them via

```
TextBox.Text = settings.Whatever;
```