# How do I make an Event in the Usercontrol and have it handled in the Main Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, event-handling

I have a custom usercontrol and I want to do something relatively simple.

When ever a numeric up down in that usercontrol's value changes, have the main form update a display window.

This is not a problem if the NUD was not in a usercontrol but I can't seem to figure out how to have the event handled by the mainform and not the usercontrol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms user controls custom events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188059/winforms-user-controls-custom-events)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You need to create an event handler for the user control that is raised when an event from within the user control is fired. This will allow you to bubble the event up the chain so you can handle the event from the form.

When clicking `Button1` on the UserControl, i'll fire `Button1_Click` which triggers `UserControl_ButtonClick` on the form:

User control:

```
[Browsable(true)] [Category("Action")] 
[Description("Invoked when user clicks button")]
public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //bubble the event up to the parent
    if (this.ButtonClick!= null)
        this.ButtonClick(this, e);               
}
```

Form:

```
UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick);

protected void UserControl_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //handle the event 
}
```

**Notes:**

- Newer Visual Studio versions suggest that instead of `if (this.ButtonClick!= null) this.ButtonClick(this, e);` you can use `ButtonClick?.Invoke(this, e);`, which does essentially the same, but is shorter.
- The `Browsable` attribute makes the event visible in Visual Studio's designer (events view), `Category` shows it in the "Action" category, and `Description` provides a description for it. You can omit these attributes completely, but making it available to the designer it is much more comfortable, since VS handles it for you.

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work on user control instances that are inside  repeater control that generates them on the OnItemDatabound event. It is as if the `UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick);` part is not doing anything. `if (this.ButtonClick!= null)` always returns false.

Comment: @Osprey: Inside of a repeater, you would probably want to add the handler declaratively in the markup, e.g. `<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />`. Otherwise, you would need to find the user control during data binding of the repeater and attach the event handler there.

Answer (score 28):

Try mapping it.  Try placing this code in your `UserControl`:

```
public event EventHandler ValueChanged {
  add { numericUpDown1.ValueChanged += value; }
  remove { numericUpDown1.ValueChanged -= value; }
}
```

then your `UserControl` will have the `ValueChanged` event you normally see with the `NumericUpDown` control.

Comment: Don't use the *new* keyword here.

Answer (score 14):

you can do like this.....the below example shows text box(user control) value changed

```
   // Declare a delegate 
public delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e);
public partial class SampleUserControl : TextBox 
{    
    public SampleUserControl() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    // Declare an event 
    public event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged;

    protected virtual void OnValueChanged(ValueChangedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (ValueChanged != null) 
            ValueChanged(this,e); 
    }    
    private void SampleUserControl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        TextBox tb  = (TextBox)sender; 
        int value; 
        if (!int.TryParse(tb.Text, out value)) 
            value = 0; 
        // Raise the event 
       OnValueChanged( new ValueChangedEventArgs(value)); 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the easy way to do that is use landa function without any problem like

```
userControl_Material1.simpleButton4.Click += (s, ee) =>
            {
                Save_mat(mat_global);
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

For those looking to do this in VB, here's how I got mine to work with a checkbox.

Background: I was trying to make my own checkbox that is a slider/switch control. I've only included the relevant code for this question.

#### In User control MyCheckbox.ascx

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

#### In User control MyCheckbox.ascx.vb

Create an EventHandler (OnCheckChanged).  When an event fires on the control    (ID="checkbox") inside your    usercontrol (MyCheckBox.ascx), then fire your EventHandler (OnCheckChanged).

```
Public Event OnCheckChanged As EventHandler

Private Sub checkbox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles checkbox.CheckedChanged
    RaiseEvent OnCheckChanged(Me, e)
End Sub
```

#### In Page MyPage.aspx

```
<uc:MyCheckbox runat="server" ID="myCheck" OnCheckChanged="myCheck_CheckChanged" />
```

Note: myCheck_CheckChanged didn't fire until I added the **Handles** clause below

#### In Page MyPage.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub myCheck_CheckChanged (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles scTransparentVoting.OnCheckChanged
    'Do some page logic here
End Sub
```

Comment: I know you answered this 2 years ago, but the question was in regards to WinForms, and not ASP.Net - while the general idea is similar (using event handlers) the implementation in WinForms would be different