# Can't access event in

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I've got a problem with subscribing from a form to an event in an user control.

MainForm-Code:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserControl menuView = new mnlib.mnlibControl();
        newWindow(menuView);
    }

    public void newWindow(UserControl control)
    {
        this.mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
        this.mainPanel.Controls.Add(control);
    }

    mnlibControl.OnLearnClick += new EventHandler(ButtonClick); //Error in this line

    protected void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //handling..
    }
}
```

UserControl-Code:

```
public partial class mnlibControl : UserControl
{
    public mnlibControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_beenden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    public event EventHandler LearnClick;
    private void btn_lernen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.LearnClick != null)
            this.LearnClick(this, e);
    }
}
```

Now, visual studio marks the "mnlibControl.OnLearnClick ..." line as wrong. "mnlibControl" would not be found, maybe a missing using directive etc. .
All this code and both forms are located in the same project file.
I tried around and googled like hell but just can't find a solution for my problem.

In the UserControl form there is a button - when it's clicket it shall trigger the newWindow method in the mainForm and open up another window.

My source for this solution of my problem is: [How do I make an Event in the Usercontrol and Have it Handeled in the Main Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880850/how-do-i-make-an-event-in-the-usercontrol-and-have-it-handeled-in-the-main-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `OnLearnClick` in your component. You need to subscribe to `LearnClick`. You also need to subscribe in function block. You also should use concrete type (`mnlib.mnlibControl`), not `UserControl`:

```
public mainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mnlib.mnlibControl menuView = new mnlib.mnlibControl();
    menuView.LearnClick += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
    newWindow(menuView);
}
```

Comment: With exactly this code it works until the "LearnClick" in line 5. It says there would be no definition for LearnClick.

Comment: @dncrft You need to use `mnlib.mnlibControl` instead of `UserControl`. See the updated answer for details

Comment: Finally, this works! Thank you! No idea why I used     UserControl     instead of     mnlib.mnlibControl     .. kind of stupid ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your code `mnlibControl.OnLearnClick += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);` must be within any of functional block (i.e. method, property, ...).

Comment: Also in this case, when I put the code in the mainForm brackets it says there would be no definition for OnLearnClick in mnlib.mnlibControl. If i change "OnLearnClick" to "LearnClick" it says, I need an object reference for "mnlib.mnlibControl.LearnClick"

Answer (score 1):

You have to place this line inside an actual method:

```
mnlibControl.LearnClick += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
```

Like this:

```
public mainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UserControl menuView = new mnlib.mnlibControl();
    newWindow(menuView);
    mnlibControl.OnLearnClick += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);
}
```

Comment: This way it tells me, mnlibControl would not be in the actual context :/

Comment: @dncrft `mnlibControl` is a class name. You have to use the instance. I mean, what's the ID of your user control in the form??