# how can an event in usercontrol get detected by the main aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

How can I "bubble" up an event from a usercontrol to the main page? However the usercontrol is not always loaded as I am using update panels to ajax in different usercontrols.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880850/how-do-i-make-an-event-in-the-usercontrol-and-have-it-handeled-in-the-main-form) but it assumes the usercontrol is always loaded?

Edit:
I looked at tutorials but for some reason it takes two for the event work.

This is the button to be pressed and its code behind callback

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="profileSignOut" CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClick="profileSignOut_Click" Text="Sign Out"/>

protected void profileSignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        infoTB.Text += "\nclicked";
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        if (SignOut != null)
        SignOut(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

The event defined in the usercontrol, had to be static otherwise the event handler in the main page would throw an error

```
public static event EventHandler SignOut;
```

and the handler in the main page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Views.Profile.SignOut += new EventHandler(signOutEvent);
        LoadUserControl();
    }
private void signOutEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuButtons.Visible = true;
        LastLoadedControl = null;
        LoadUserControl();
    }
```

Comment: Even in asynchronous postbacks the page (and all controls like also the `UserControl`) will run through their whole life-cycle.Declare a custom event in the usercontrol and register that in the page, so that you can handle it there. You find a tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3

Comment: What does that mean exactly? I am still having trouble implementing the solution in that link too. `Views.Profile.SignOut += new EventHandler(signOutEvent);` isn't working to set the event handler in the main page.

Comment: I have added a link to a tutorial in my comment.

Comment: I'll take a look - an error is being thrown saying the event in the usercontrol needs to be static? is that correct?