# How to get User Control from a PictureBox

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a PictureBox on my user control and I have added lots of this User Control on my form. Thing is whenever a user clicks on PictureBox he should get that User Control item to which this PictureBox belongs.

So, on my **User Control** I have added this code

```
  public usercontrol1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      pictureBox1.Parent = this;
   }
```

Then on my **Form**

```
  private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var c = new usercontrol1();
       c.pictureBox1.Click += item_click;
       c = new usercontrol1();
       c.pictureBox1.Click += item_click;
   }

   private void item_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       usercontrol1 abc = pictureBox1.Parent; // Giving Error
   }
```

I tried this approach to set user control as parent control of picturebox and tried to retrieve it from picturebox click event on form. But resulting in failure. How do I get the usercontrol1 object from PictureBox click event?

Comment: If the PictureBox is in the UserControl, then its parent is already the UserControl.  Your code created new UserControls, but didn't add them to the form.  I suspect you want to do something like this: [How do I make an Event in the Usercontrol and have it handled in the Main Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7880850/719186)

Comment: the last two lines in Load are redundant. b) the uc c is never added to a controls collection. c) in the item_click you should cast the sender to picturebox (or control); then you can access its Parent.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to type it here but there I have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the error message (you forgot to tell us) pretty clearly tells you what is wrong: `pictureBox1.Parent` is of type `Control` and therefor cannot be assigned directly to variable of type `usercontrol1`.

You have to **cast** it to `usercontrol1`:

```
usercontrol1 abc = (usercontrol1)pictureBox1.Parent;
```

Note that this will throw an `InvalidCastException` if for any reason `Parent` is some other `Control` than a `usercontrol1`. So you better use the `as` operator:

```
private void item_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    usercontrol1 abc = pictureBox1.Parent as usercontrol1;
    if (abc == null) return; // as returns null if the cast fails

    // do something with abc
}
```

or use the enhanced (pattern matching) `is` operator in C#7:

```
private void item_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!pictureBox1.Parent is usercontrol1 abc) return;

    // do something with abc
}
```