# How can I draw a line in my form from another class?

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes in my program:

- **Arrow** (it contains the logic for drawing arrow, and all required information about it, like: starting point, ending point, etc.)
- **Form1** (that contains the drawing area(basically panel), where this arrow will be located in the future)
- **UserControl**, is located in `Form1` (I did `Form1.Controls.Add(UserControl)`). It has a `Form1` as a parent. In this `UserControl`, I have a button, when I click it, an arrow should be drawn on the `Form1`'s drawing area.

  And I'm so confused with the logic that this program should have. I tried to create `Arrow` class object in the `UserControl.Button_Click()`, and call all the Arrow's methods from there, but I can't access to Form1's controls. I also thought maybe I can create object of `Arrow` in the `Form1`. So I tried to subscribe event `UserControl.Button_Click()` with some `Form1`'s delegate, but I don't know how to do it. In this case, does delegate and the method that this delegate have as a reference should be Static?

So this is how my code looks like.
(I little bit simplified and shortened my classes)
Arrow:

```
public class Arrow
{
    public Point PointBeginning { get => pointBeginning; set => pointBeginning = value; }
    public Point PointEnding { get => pointEnding; set => pointEnding = value; }
    public int ArrowClickCounter { get => arrowClickCounter; set => arrowClickCounter = value; }

    public void Draw(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //code for drawing
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
public class Form1
{
    public delegate void DrawArrowDelegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
    DrawArrowDelegate drawArrowDelegate = DrawArrow;
    /* .. */

    private void DrawArrow(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Arrow arrow = new Arrow();
        arrow.PointBegining = //some point
        arrow.PointEnding = //some another point
        arrow.Draw(sender, e);
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
public class UserControl
{
    /*...*/
    
    private void button_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //And here i somehow want to call delegate. But don't know how :(
    }
}
```

Sorry for such confused code :(

Can you please recommend me something?

Comment: Please post some code from your project.

Comment: Are you talking about WinForms? Know how to [communicate between two forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665533/) before going any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `Arrow` class could potentially have a `DrawMethod` which takes a control
2. Your `UserControl`, should [publish *events*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880850/how-do-i-make-an-event-in-the-usercontrol-and-have-it-handled-in-the-main-form)
3. You *form* should listen to the UserControl *Events*
4. Your *form* should override `OnPaint` to draw the method on demand

Comment: I guess i have a problems with 3. How can i listen it from form? Can you please give me some links where i can read about that? Thank you

Comment: @Svemir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880850/how-do-i-make-an-event-in-the-usercontrol-and-have-it-handled-in-the-main-form

Comment: sorry again, i'm going through this code from this link, but i have one question. In the form we writing UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick); But here UserControl1 is an object of UserControl, right? But in my program i have a lot of userControls that creating dynamically in the code. So how can i use UserControl1.ButtonClick without setting it to specific object of UserControl class but for all objects? Sorry for such silly quiestion.

Comment: @Svemir You will need to set them in code. Maybe best to ask another question, reference to question i sent, show your code where you are creating these in your own code. This will be easily answered. however its hard to do in comments

Comment: @Svemir , you can do `UserControl.Click += Usercontrol_click;` (**If your** `UserControl` **contains a click event, that is**)

Comment: @MichaelRandall thank you for your help! Finally i remember where i putting in my code UserControls to the Form, so now i just do userControl.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl_ButtonClick); It works perfect! Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

Arrow class:

```
    public class Arrow
    {
        public Point PointBeginning { get; set; }
        public Point PointEnding { get; set; }
        public int ArrowClickCounter { get; set; }

        public void Draw()
        {
            //code for drawing
        }
    }
```

UserControl.cs:

```
    public delegate void CreateArrowEventArgs(Arrow arrow);
    public event CreateArrowEventArgs OnCreateArrow; 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.OnCreateArrow!=null)
        {
            // Create Arrow object which you will have access to in your Form
            Arrow arrowToDraw = new Arrow();

            // Fire The Event
            this.OnCreateArrow.Invoke(arrowToDraw);
        }
    }
```

Form codebehind :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create User Control
        var UserCtrl = new UserControl1();

        // Register Event
        UserCtrl.OnCreateArrow += UserCtrl_OnCreateArrow;

        //Add Control to Form
        this.Controls.Add(UserCtrl);
    }

    // You get the Arrow object for use here
    private void UserCtrl_OnCreateArrow(Arrow arrow)
    {
        arrow.Draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like **you're having trouble accessing** `Form1`**'s Controls, so try this:**

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();

foreach(Button b in f1.Controls)
{
  //Your code..
}
```

There's also:

```
this.Controls
```

And, with calling the events of another control,

```
button1_Click(sender, e);
```

As for adding an event to the click of, say, a button,

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

Those should work to access the controls.

I can provide more information if needed :)

Comment: This access controls in a new Form1 you just created and never displayed, not the existing form.

Comment: Sorry, i explained my problem not properly, i guess, sorry for that :( I mean, i have a form and have a UserControl with button, and when i click on the button i want to call some methods on the form. But thank you, anyway for your answer!

Comment: You could use, for example, `Button1_Click(sender, e);`

Comment: @DourHighArch , I know - **If you want to access the current _existing_ form, do** `this.Controls`

Comment: @Svemir **no problem! :)**